# Power Query filling down empty cell unit new value, then fill down with that value

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I need to fill down Column B with the first value available until it hits a value already contained in the cell below then proceed with filling down with that value so on and so forth.

See my table below. Again this question pertains to filling blank cells in Column B.

How would I go about doing this in Power Query?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
= Table.FillDown(YourTable,{"Product Number"})
```

Comment: Yea i tried that, it did not fill down the column. Any idea as to why? An applied step was created without any errors but it did not work as intended

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution. It was not filling down due to the cells being blank. What I did was I "Replaced Values" blank with null, then I did fill down command and it filled down the entire column correctly.